# How to change the background color of NavigationExperimental's NavigationCardStack on React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, react-native, reactjs

I tried `style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}` inside `NavigationCardStack` but it doesn't work.

In React Native, is it possible to change the background color of `NavigationExperimental`'s `NavigationCardStack`? If so what would be the proper way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I believe **NavigationCardStack** does not have style property. If you want to change the background color change the color of view in **renderScene**.

Update: I just checked and it does have style property. Can you add more code?

Comment: Really? I guess I'll give that a try then. Also for `NavigationExperimental`'s `NavigationHeader`, how can I hide the navigation bar's 1px hairline? I tried doing `shadowHidden={true}` but it is not provided unfortunately.

Comment: what you mean by 1px hairline

Comment: There is a 1px line right beneath a navigation bar. You can see it better if you set the background to transparent. Just want to get rid of it

Comment: just checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: @JoKo did you find any solutions?